# Flash plays unwanted sound on DOWN event

Tags: flash, button, audio

I'm newbie in flash. I have created a button - it looks perfect. I got seperate keyframes for UP, OVER, DOWN and HIT events. The OVER (and only it) has assigned the sound. The problem is flash plays sound (assigned to OVER) for DOWN event (no sound assigned). I have no idea what is wrong, tried everything with this. I am unable to find soultion,

Thank You in advance!

PS sorry about my english again (I do my best)

Answer (score 1):

Put the same sound in the down keyframe with the action stop from it's properties.
You can put the separate sound for the hit frame. And it works as it should.
I couldn't find the answer anywhere and somehow I got onto this solution :)

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your timline, I'm guessing that you have a keyframe on the Over state but you also have frames on the same layer in the down and hit state, which indicates to Flash to play the sound for all 3 frames. You can insert a blank keyframe on the layer with the sound on the Down frame if my guess is right.

Comment: Thank Yoy for really fast response. My timeline looks like this http://qkpic.com/13178.